# Visual Studio 2015 não aparacem ASP.NET Preview Templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Instalei a versão Pro do Visual Studio 2015 no Windows 10, para testar.

Ao criar um projeto deveria abrir uma tela com as opções como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas abre assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não mostra as opções do ASP.NET 5 Templates.

Tentei adicionar por Tools -> Extensions sem sucesso.

Usei a opção Repair e nada também. Inclusive a opçãção "Web Developer Tools" marcada.

Vi alguns post´s que só resolveram o problema formatando a máquina.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema clicando no ícone de notificações e atualizando o Visual Studio clicando no links disponíveis.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]